# Undefined property in angular, to show uploaded documents

Tags: angular

I am working at a angular application 6. And I want to show a list of uploaded documents. There is a component for. But the properties of that component are not initialized. But how to do that?

I have this component:

```
export class DiplomaComponent extends AfwComponent implements OnInit {
    resources: DiplomasResourcesModel;
    private readonly apiDiploma: string = 'api/register/teachers/current/diploma';
    readonly resourceKeys: DiplomasResourcesModel = DiplomasResourcesModel.keys;
    readonly linkModifyDiploma = RoutesRegisterModel.pathnameMyRegisterRouteDiplomaEdit;

    //private readonly apiDiploma: string = 'api/register/teachers/current/diploma';
    //readonly resourceKeys = DiplomasWijzigenResourcesModel.keys;

    protected readonly formName = FormNamesModel.diplomaForm;
    //diplomaModel : DiplomaModel;
    formModel: AfwFormService;
    //documentList?: DocumentListModel;
    @Input() readonly diplomaModel: DiplomaModel;
    documentListCompoment: DocumentListComponent;
    diplomaFormKeysModel: DiplomaFormKeysModel;
    protected baseDocumentsUrl: string;
    teacher: TeacherModel;
    protected hasDocumentsInQueue: boolean;
    id: number;
    isSucceeded: boolean;
    documentList?: DocumentListModel;
   //private readonly http: any;


    constructor(readonly textResourceService: TextResourceService,
         readonly route: ActivatedRoute, private readonly  https: AfwHttp,
         private readonly multiFileUploadControlFactory: MultiFileUploadControlFactory,
         private readonly formService: FormService,
         )  {


        super(textResourceService, route);

        //this.diplomaModel = diplomaModel;
    }



    ngOnInit() {

        //showDocuments();
        const defaultModel = diplomaFormModel(this.multiFileUploadControlFactory);
        //this.diplomaService.getDiplomaDocumentList();

         this.getDocumentsDetails().subscribe(d => {
            const diplomasUpload = this.multiFileUploadControlFactory.createEmptyDefaultValues();
            diplomasUpload.files = d.documents;
            this.formModel = this.formService.createModel<DiplomaFormModel, DiplomasResourcesModel>(
                defaultModel, { qualificationTerms: null, diplomasUpload }, this.resources
            );
        });
    }

    /* getDocumentDiploma() {
        this.diplomaService.getDiplomaDocumentList();

    } */

    showDocuments(): boolean {
        return this.diplomaModel.documents &&
            this.diplomaModel.documents.hasDocuments() || !this.diplomaModel.documents.isSucceeded;
    }

     getDocumentsDetails = (): Observable<DocumentListModel> =>
     this.https.get<DiplomaModel>(`${this.apiDiploma}/documents`).pipe(map((dip => dip.documents)))


}
```

And this is the html:

```
<ng-container>
    <afw-lead resourceKey="diplomaVoegToeLabel" [text]="resources.diplomaVoegToeLabel"></afw-lead>

    <afw-content-block [resources]="resources" [titleResourceKey]="resourceKeys.diplomasTitel" [editLink]="linkModifyDiploma"
        [editLinkResourceKey]="resourceKeys.wijzigenLink">
        <div class="readonly-block">
            <p [textContent]="resources.diplomasLabel"></p>
        </div>

        <afw-document-list  [emptyResourceKey]="resourceKeys.geenBestandenTekst"
            [baseDocumentsUrl]="baseDocumentsUrl" [fieldValue]="documentList" [resources]="resources"
            fieldResourceKeyPrefix="bijlagen" [getDocumentsDetails] = 'getDocumentsDetails'>
        </afw-document-list>
    </afw-content-block>
</ng-container>
```

But I get this error:

```
DocumentListComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSucceeded' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DocumentListComponent.html:3)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:22477)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21873)
    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)
    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)
```

and this is the component DocumentListModel:

```
import { DocumentModel } from 'afw/models';

/**
 * The model for documents that contains information about all the documents of the user
 * and document store queue for particular case number.
 */
export class DocumentListModel {

    /**
     * Indicator of how many documents there are in the queue
     */
    documentsInQueue?: number;

    /**
     * The actual documents
     */
    documents: Array<DocumentModel>;

    /**
     * Whether the DMS succeeded
     */
    isSucceeded: boolean;

    /**
     * Whether there is anything to display
     */
    hasDocuments() {
        return this.isSucceeded && this.documents && this.documents.length > 0 || this.documentsInQueue > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor(item?: DocumentListModel) {
        if (item) {
            Object.assign(this, item);
        }
    }
}
```

So what I have to fix?

This is the DiplomaModel component:

```
import { DocumentListModel } from "afw/models";

export class DiplomaModel {
    documents: DocumentListModel;


}
```

and my html looks like this:

my type file script looks like this:

```
import { Component,  OnInit,  } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { TextResourceService, AfwHttp } from 'afw/generic-services';
import { AfwComponent } from 'afw/ui-components';
import { DiplomasResourcesModel } from 'lr/models/src/resources/register-resources.model';
import { RoutesRegisterModel, FormNamesModel } from 'register-shared/models';
import { TeacherModel } from 'lr/models';
import { DiplomaFormKeysModel } from './models/diploma-form-keys.model';
import { DocumentListComponent } from 'afw/ui-components/src/document-list/document-list.component';
import { DocumentListModel } from 'afw/models';
import { AfwFormService, MultiFileUploadControlFactory, FormService } from 'afw/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DiplomaModel } from './models/diploma.model';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { diplomaFormModel, DiplomaFormModel } from './models/diploma-form.model';
// import { DiplomaService } from 'register-shared/services';



@Component({
    selector: 'register-diploma',
    templateUrl: './diploma.component.html',
})
export class DiplomaComponent extends AfwComponent implements OnInit {
    resources: DiplomasResourcesModel;
    private readonly apiDiploma: string = 'api/register/teachers/current/diploma';
    readonly resourceKeys: DiplomasResourcesModel = DiplomasResourcesModel.keys;
    readonly linkModifyDiploma = RoutesRegisterModel.pathnameMyRegisterRouteDiplomaEdit;
    readonly id: number;

    //private readonly apiDiploma: string = 'api/register/teachers/current/diploma';
    //readonly resourceKeys = DiplomasWijzigenResourcesModel.keys;

    protected readonly formName = FormNamesModel.diplomaForm;
    //diplomaModel : DiplomaModel;
    formModel: AfwFormService;
    //documentList?: DocumentListModel;
    diplomaModel: DiplomaModel;
    documentListCompoment: DocumentListComponent;
    diplomaFormKeysModel: DiplomaFormKeysModel;
    protected baseDocumentsUrl: string;
    teacher: TeacherModel;
    protected hasDocumentsInQueue: boolean;

    isSucceeded: boolean;
    documentList?: DocumentListModel;
   //private readonly http: any;


    constructor(readonly textResourceService: TextResourceService,
         readonly route: ActivatedRoute, private readonly  https: AfwHttp,
         private readonly multiFileUploadControlFactory: MultiFileUploadControlFactory,
         private readonly formService: FormService,
         //private readonly diplomaService: DiplomaService
         )  {


        super(textResourceService, route);

        //this.diplomaModel = diplomaModel;
    }



    ngOnInit() {

        //showDocuments();
        const defaultModel = diplomaFormModel(this.multiFileUploadControlFactory);
        //this.diplomaService.getDiplomaDocumentList();

         this.getDocumentsDetails().subscribe(d => {
            const diplomasUpload = this.multiFileUploadControlFactory.createEmptyDefaultValues();
            diplomasUpload.files = d.documents;
            this.formModel = this.formService.createModel<DiplomaFormModel, DiplomasResourcesModel>(
                defaultModel, { qualificationTerms: null, diplomasUpload }, this.resources
            );
        });
    }

    /* getDocumentDiploma() {
        this.diplomaService.getDiplomaDocumentList();

    } */

    showDocuments(): boolean { return this.diplomaModel.documents && (this.diplomaModel.documents.hasDocuments() || !this.diplomaModel.documents.isSucceeded); }

     getDocumentsDetails = (): Observable<DocumentListModel> =>
     this.https.get<DiplomaModel>(`${this.apiDiploma}/documents`).pipe(map((dip => dip.documents)))




     //this.https.get<DiplomaModel>(`${this.apiDiploma}/documents`).pipe(map((dip => dip.documents)))


}
```

And html file:

```
<afw-content-block [resources]="resources" [titleResourceKey]="resourceKeys.diplomasTitel" [editLink]="linkModifyDiploma"
    [editLinkResourceKey]="resourceKeys.wijzigenLink">
    <div class="readonly-block">
        <p [textContent]="resources.diplomasLabel"></p>
    </div>

    <afw-document-list [resources]="resources" fieldResourceKeyPrefix="bijlagen"
        [fieldValue]="diplomaModel?.documents"
        [baseDocumentsUrl]="baseDocumentsUrl" [emptyResourceKey]="resourceKeys.geenBestandenTekst"
        [getDocumentsDetails]='getDocumentsDetails()'>
    </afw-document-list>
</afw-content-block>
```

Comment: You are referring `this.diplomaModel.documents.isSucceeded`, Does your `diplomaModel.documents` contains a property for `isSucceeded`

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: So Yes, because DocumentListModel has a property isSucceeded

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> showDocuments(): boolean {
>         return this.diplomaModel.documents &&
>             this.diplomaModel.documents.hasDocuments() || !this.diplomaModel.documents.isSucceeded;
>     }
> ```

do you mean:

> ```
> showDocuments(): boolean {
>         return this.diplomaModel.documents 
>             && (this.diplomaModel.documents.hasDocuments() || !this.diplomaModel.documents.map(d => d.isSucceeded).reduce((p, n) => p && n, true));
>     }
> ```

??

Because documents is array of objects... not single object

Comment: But then I get this error: property 'map' does not exist on type: DocumentListModel

Comment: Sory...
It was my mistake...
because this.diplomaModel is a DiplomaModel type
and it contains "documents"
so...
solution for it should be... brackets:
showDocuments(): boolean {
        return this.diplomaModel.documents &&
            (this.diplomaModel.documents.hasDocuments() || !this.diplomaModel.documents.isSucceeded);
    }

because without it you don't check if it's null for last condition